# How to RE-set table prefix for CakePhp plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins

Cakephp(2.6) Application uses specific prefix for all of its tables, configured in database.php. A newly added plugin is using its own tables and I would rather not touch them.

How can I reset/reconfigure prefix for any given/or all plugins? I do not want to touch plugin models which is what I understand is one way of reconfiguring prefixes.

Comment: Assuming the plugin's models are correctly extending AppModel and doesn't reset the prefix themselves do they not inherit your app's prefix (assuming you've defined this in AppModel)?

Comment: If you have models using a connection with a prefix, and _don't_ want a prefix - then you need the models to use a different connection (it can be a copy of the existing connection - but it can't be the same one as "use this prefix except for that table" isn't possible with a _connection_ table prefix).

Comment: AD7six I think that is the answer that I was looking for... although I will need to figure out how to make it use a different connection.. thanks